# Install pandas >= 0.23 in Oracle Linux

Tags: python, linux, pandas

I'm trying to install argcis package using pip inside a Python virtual environment in a Oracle Linux machine. Upon installation, arcgis requests for pandas >= 0.23. However, when trying to install pandas >=0.23 I get the following error:

```
(venv) [opc@srv-00-21-052 notebooks]$ pip install 'pandas>=0.23'
Collecting pandas>=0.23
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas>=0.23 (from 
versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 
0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 
0.8.0rc2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 
0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 
0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0rc1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0rc1, 0.20.0, 
0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0rc1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0)
No matching distribution found for pandas>=0.23
```

I've tried updating system packages with no result. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python version was the problem. Upgraded from 3.4.8 to 3.6.3 and everything worked as expected.